# How to avoid the connection error when I am opening a website automatically?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, debian, python-requests

I am web-scraping a few websites on Debian with Python 2.7, but maybe my code automatically stop (if it can't load in time (freeze) or there isn't an internet connection).

Is there any solution to solve this, and maybe just skip the problem and run my code to the next URL? Because if I get a problem like this, this script just stop automatically..

Here my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#!/bin/sh
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import urllib2
import subprocess
import unicodecsv as csv
import os
import sys
import io
import time
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import MySQLdb
import re
import contextlib
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
import pyautogui 
from pykeyboard import PyKeyboard

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')


cols = ['MYCOLS..'] 

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
datatable=[]

browser.get('LINK1')
time.sleep(5)

browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(text(), "CLICK EVENT")]').click()
time.sleep(5)
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(text(), "CLICK EVENT")]').click()
html = browser.page_source
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
table = soup.find('table', { "class" : "table table-condensed table-hover data-table m-n-t-15" })    

for record in table.find_all('tr', class_="hidden-xs hidden-sm ng-scope"):   
    for data in record.find_all("td"):
        temp_data.append(data.text.encode('utf-8'))
    newlist = filter(None, temp_data)
    datatable.append(newlist)
       
time.sleep(10) 
browser.close()

#HERE I INSERT MY DATAES INTO MYSQL..IT IS NOT IMPORTANT, AND MY SECOND LINK STARTING HERE

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
datatable=[]
   
browser.get('LINK2')
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(text(), "LCLICK EVENT")]').click()
time.sleep(5)
html = browser.page_source
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
table = soup.find('table', { "class" : "table table-condensed table-hover data-table m-n-t-15" })

for record in table.find_all('tr', class_="hidden-xs hidden-sm ng-scope"):   
    for data in record.find_all("td"):
        temp_data.append(data.text.encode('utf-8'))
    newlist = filter(None, temp_data)
    datatable.append(newlist)
       
time.sleep(10) 
browser.close()

#MYSQLDB PART AGAIN...AND THE NEXT LINK IS COMING.
```

+1 EDIT:

When the script not find this CLICK EVENT stop too. Why? How can I avoid this?

Comment: two things, 1. make your code modeler 1. use exception handling

Answer (score 0):

Using Selenium, you can configure your driver (browser object) to wait for specific elements or condition. Then you may use regular try/except to handle any error, for instance `TimeoutException` or many others.

Selenium explained the wait system pretty well on [their documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).

Here is a code snippet for exception handling on Selenium :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

try:
    # Wait for any element / condition, you can even had lambda if you wish to
    WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.ID, 'my-item'))
    )
except TimeoutException:
    # Here I raise an error but you can do whatever you want like exiting properly or logging something
    raise RuntimeError('No Internet connection')
```

Comment: For example i can wait for a button? This is the example webpage: https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/grz/departures and my code:  browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(text(), "Load earlier flights")]').click()  , How can I build it into my code and where i have to put?

Comment: I won't do everything for you, I gave you a tip. Now using Selenium you can easily build so, just see their documentation

Comment: I just asked with a correct example..thank you anyway.

Comment: Just use WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, 'YOUR XPATH'))
    ) in a try/except. If nothing is wrong, then you know you can get your element